# XmlRootElement GenericEntity Jersey and Resteasy

Tags: jersey, jax-rs, resteasy, java-ee-7

In my Java EE project I am working with JAX-RS. Sometimes I need a collection to be returned. The idea is to keep the implementation generic as possible so I can easily deploy between different app servers. When I use `GenericEntity` on a `List<?>` I get 2 different XmlRootElements on Resteasy (Wildfly) and Jersey (Glassfish). My entry point:

```
@Path("/example")
@RequestScoped
public class ExampleResponse {

    @GET
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
    public Response getResponse() {
        List<TestEntity> entities = new ArrayList<>();
        entities.add(new TestEntity());
        entities.add(new TestEntity());
        entities.add(new TestEntity());

        GenericEntity<List<TestEntity>> generic = new GenericEntity<List<TestEntity>>(entities){};

        return Response.ok().entity(generic).build();
    }
}
```

Result with Resteasy:

```
<collection> <!--root element collection-->
    <testEntity>
        <val1>Hi</val1>
        <val2>Bye</val2>
    </testEntity>
    <testEntity>
        <val1>Hi</val1>
        <val2>Bye</val2>
    </testEntity>
    <testEntity>
        <val1>Hi</val1>
        <val2>Bye</val2>
    </testEntity>
</collection>
```

Result with Jersey:

```
<testEntities> <!--root element plural-->
    <testEntity>
        <val1>Hi</val1>
        <val2>Bye</val2>
    </testEntity>
    <testEntity>
        <val1>Hi</val1>
        <val2>Bye</val2>
    </testEntity>
    <testEntity>
        <val1>Hi</val1>
        <val2>Bye</val2>
    </testEntity>
</testEntities>
```

Is it possible through configuration to use either plural root elements with Resteasy or collection root elements with Jersey? I know it is possible to create a wrapper class to do it, but that doesn't seem the way to go.

Comment: With Jersey, it looks like the behavior [is hard coded](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/media/jaxb/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/jaxb/internal/XmlCollectionJaxbProvider.java#L178) with no configurable properties.

Comment: Looking at the RESTeasy source code, it looks like [it's configurable with @Wrapped](https://github.com/resteasy/Resteasy/blob/master/jaxrs/providers/jaxb/src/main/java/org/jboss/resteasy/plugins/providers/jaxb/CollectionProvider.java#L343) annotation on the method. Don't quote me, I never tried it.

Comment: @peeskillet thanks a lot for your answers. The `@Wrapper` is a Resteasy specific annotation, which I try to avoid. I will probably have to write wrapper classes in order to have a safe/consistent responses.

Comment: One portable solution I can think of that would eliminate the wrapper class, is to use [`jackson-jaxrs-xml-provider`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-jaxrs-providers/blob/master/xml/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/jaxrs/xml/JacksonXMLProvider.java). It supports JAXB annotations (for the most part). You would have to figure out how to disable the providers in Glassfish and Wildfly (if they aren't already disabled by just adding a different provider)